# how to rotate SmartArtNode text aspose.slide

Tags: asp.net, aspose-slides

How to rotate `SmartArtNode` text aspose.slide

I use:

```
tmNode.TextFrame.TextFrameFormat.RotationAngle = 90
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your requirements and suggest you to please try using Aspose.Slides for.NET 17.1.0 using following sample code. I am able to observe the rotation effect on text. I hope this will be helpful. You may also contact us in [Aspose.Slides forums](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.slides-product-family/109/showforum.aspx) if there is any further inquiry.

```
using (Presentation presentation = new Presentation())
{
    // Accessing the slide
    ISlide slide = presentation.Slides[0];

    // Adding SmartArt shape and nodes
    var chevron = slide.Shapes.AddSmartArt(10, 10, 800, 60, SmartArtLayoutType.ClosedChevronProcess);
    var node = chevron.AllNodes.AddNode();
    node.TextFrame.Text = "Some text";

    node.TextFrame.TextFrameFormat.RotationAngle = 90;
    // Saving Presentation
    presentation.Save(dataDir + "FillFormat_SmartArt_ShapeNode_out.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.